# Python function - Global variable not defined

Tags: python

I joined a course to learn programming with Python. For a certain assignment we had to write the code which I have pasted below.

This part of the code consist of two functions, the first one being `make_str_from_row` and the second one being `contains_word_in_row`. As you might have noticed the second function reuses the first function. I already have passed the first function but I cannot pass the second one because when it has to reuse it gives an error about the first function, which is confusing because I did not get any errors for my first function. It says that global variable `row_index` is not defined.

By the way the second function has been given in a starter code so it cannot be wrong. I don't know what's wrong, especially because I have passed the code which presumable has to be wrong.

I tried asking the team for some feedback in case it might be some error in the grader but it has been a week and I have had no reply while the deadline is 2 days away. I am not asking for answers here I only would like to ask somebody for an explanation about the given error so I can figure out a solution myself. I would really appreciate the help.

```
def makestrfromrow(board, rowindex):
    """ (list of list of str, int) -> str

    Return the characters from the row of the board with index row_index
    as a single string.

    >>> make_str_from_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
    'ANTT'
    """

    string = ''
    for i in board[row_index]:
        string = string + i
    return string

def boardcontainswordinrow(board, word):
    """ (list of list of str, str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if one or more of the rows of the board contains
    word.

    Precondition: board has at least one row and one column, and word is a
    valid word.

    >>> board_contains_word_in_row([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'SOB')
    True
    """

    for row_index in range(len(board)):
        if word in make_str_from_row(board, row_index):
            return True

    return False
```

Comment: When posting Python questions, you absolutely must doublecheck your indentation. Your code samples are obviously broken and in Python it's generally impossible for anyone else to say how they're supposed to work.

Comment: Have a close look how your variables are named. Hint: The `_` (underscore) is relevant.

Comment: Your `makestrfromrow` sure is a long-winded way to say `"".join(board[rowindex])`...

Answer (score 4):

You named the argument `rowindex` but use the name `row_index` in the function body.

Fix one or the other.

Demo, fixing the name used in the body of the function to match the argument:

```
>>> def makestrfromrow(board, rowindex):
...     string = ''
...     for i in board[rowindex]:
...         string = string + i
...     return string
... 
>>> makestrfromrow([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 0)
'ANTT'
```

Do note that both this function and `boardcontainswordinrow` are *not* consistent with the docstring; there they are named as `make_str_from_row` and `board_contains_word_in_row`. Your `boardcontainswordinrow` function *uses* `make_str_from_row`, not `makestrfromrow`, so you'll have to correct that as well; one direction or the other.

Comment: For some reason that must have happened after posting. I checked my code and both the argument name and the variable name have the underscore.

Comment: The error you posted is entirely consistent with this mistake.

Comment: I dont understand. The original code does have the underscores so it has to be a different reason.

Comment: @user2756101: Then *use* the version without underscores in `boardcontainswordinrow` too. You have to stick to one or the other.

Comment: No that is not what I mean. All the codes have the underscores I have double-checked this. When I posted the code on this website some of the underscores disappeared. So the underscores are at the right place. I also just got a reaction from the team but they say that they are just as baffled as I am because their code exactly matches mine and has passed all the tests.

Comment: Underscores *don't just disappear*, the site does not magically remove them. The error you included in your post is the exact error you'd get if your code was missing an underscore in the argument name.

Comment: @user2756101: Do you still have the full traceback? The error message you got when the code did not run correctly? Not just the exception message itself, but the whole multi-line message with the call stack.

Comment: @user2756101: I do not have the traceback because the error is only given by the auto grader, which only gives me this line:Message:
ERROR: NameError
global name 'row_index' is not defined

The python shell and the visualizer all accept my code. 

Different people including the course team compared it to their codes and they could not find errors inside the body. Somebody suggested that it might have to do with inadverted indentions and non printable characters and that rewriting from scratch might be a solution. Did anybody encounter such a problem before?